# Thymeleaf form handling JPA transaction

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am converting a web application that used jsp to Thymeleaf with Spring Boot. My user registration page is returning an Internal Server Error status= 500 when the user submits the form to create their account. Below is from Console when logging is set to debug.

```
11:19:48.770 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter#104 Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@61351829
11:19:48.772 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]#181 Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.sub.account.service.SecurityServiceImpl.autologin(SecurityServiceImpl.java:38)
    at org.sub.web.controller.WelcomeController.registration(WelcomeController.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

Line 68 from WelcomeController:

```
securityService.autologin(userForm.getUsername(), userForm.getPasswordConfirm());
```

Line 38 from SecurityServiceImpl:

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, password, userDetails.getAuthorities());
```

As you can see below in this snippet from my WelcomeController, @ModelAttribute is specified as "userForm".

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registration(@ModelAttribute("userForm") User userForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        userValidator.validate(userForm, bindingResult);

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "registration";
        }

        userService.save(userForm);

        securityService.autologin(userForm.getUsername(), userForm.getPasswordConfirm());

        return "redirect:/welcome";
    }
```

My form th:object specifically says "userForm"

```
 <form action="#" th:action="@{/registration.html}" th:object="${userForm}" method="POST">
```

I set my th:fields to what I had as path when they were jsp files.

```
 <input type="text" th:field="*{username}" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"></input>
```

...

```
<input type="password" th:field="*{password}"  class="form-control" placeholder="Password"></input>
```

..

```
<input type="password" th:field="*{passwordConfirm}"  class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm your password"></input>
```

Comment: If you are converting to Spring Boot, you should consider using Spring Security instead of building your own, because security is much harder than most developer think. For instance it looks like your form does not post a CSRF token, and you don't change the JSessionID after login. Two things Spring Security would handle. I know that this will probably mean quite a bit of extra work, but if you work for an EU based company, leaking confidential personal data can be fined up to 4% of annual revenue, so even the business understands the importance of security.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Can I use something like this guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/ to apply Spring Security to my existing account model (user and role repositories)?

Comment: More or less, the example uses a `AuthenticationManagerBuilder ` to construct an in-memory `AuthenticationManager`, you probably need to query a database, check the Password and lookup the roles hopefully using JPA. I have some sample spring boot application I use for training https://bitbucket.org/Klaus_Groenbaek/performance, check out `dk.groenbaek.stateful.Application` it shows how to configure a `AuthenticationManager` with hard coded credentials, and should give you an idea of how it works.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful to get me going.